# Golangでの[]uintから[]byteへの変換

Tags: go

[]uint の変数を、[]byte に変換したいです。
何か良い解決方法はありませんか…？

Comment: 標準パッケージの `encoding/binary` に `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32()` などが用意されているのでそれを使ってみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: forループが最も良い方法です。効率を気にするなら設計段階で[]byteで元の値を持つようにしましょう。uintなゲッターメソッドを持つエイリアス型を定義しちゃいましょう。

Answer (score 2):

質問の内容が不明確なのでその結果次第で回答が異なります。

## uint のスライスの中身をダウンキャストして byte のスライスにしたい

nobonobo さんの仰る様にループで変換して下さい

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func UintSliceToByteSlice(us []uint) []byte {
    b := make([]byte, len(us))
    for i, v := range us {
        b[i] = byte(v)
    }
    return b
}

func main() {
    u := []uint{1,2,3}

    b := UintSliceToByteSlice(u[:])
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

結果は 1,2,3,4 の byte 型スライスになります。

## uint のスライス内容をメモリブロックとして byte のスライスに変換したい

エンディアンに依存します。uint (uint32 or uint64)がメモリ上にどの様に格納されているかで結果が異なります。以下はネットワークバイトオーダーとして使われるビッグエンディアンの場合の例です。

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    u := []uint{1,2,3,4}

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for _, v := range u {
        err := binary.Write(&buf, binary.BigEndian, uint32(v))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
}
```

結果は `[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4]` になります。uint はプラットフォームによりサイズが変わりますので始めからサイズを決め打ちできるのならば以下の様に書く事が出来ます。

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    u := []uint32{1,2,3,4}

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := binary.Write(&buf, binary.BigEndian, u)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
}
```